# How to set succeeding row values as empty if same with previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I convert this table:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+
|       PropertyName  |           Emergency           | Count | Total |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+
| IH                  | No                            |     8 |    12 |
| IH                  | No Water                      |     1 |    12 |
| IH                  | Smoke  Alarm not working      |     1 |    12 |
| IH                  | Broken Lock - Exterior        |     1 |    12 |
| IH                  | Leaking Water                 |     1 |    12 |
| GG                  | No                            |     5 |    10 |
| GG                  | Leaking Water                 |     3 |    10 |
| GG                  | Property Damage (Significant) |     1 |    10 |
| GG                  | Toilet - Clogged (1 Bathroom) |     1 |    10 |
| PLB                 | No                            |     5 |    10 |
| PLB                 | Resident Locked Out           |     2 |    10 |
| PLB                 | Smoke  Alarm not working      |     1 |    10 |
| PLB                 | Tub - Clogged (1 Bathroom)    |     1 |    10 |
| PLB                 | Leaking Water                 |     1 |    10 |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+
```

to something like this:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+
|       PropertyName  |           Emergency           | Count | Total |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+
| IH                  | No                            |     8 |    12 |
|                     | No Water                      |     1 |       |
|                     | Smoke  Alarm not working      |     1 |       |
|                     | Broken Lock - Exterior        |     1 |       |
|                     | Leaking Water                 |     1 |       |
| GG                  | No                            |     5 |    10 |
|                     | Leaking Water                 |     3 |       |
|                     | Property Damage (Significant) |     1 |       |
|                     | Toilet - Clogged (1 Bathroom) |     1 |       |
| PLB                 | No                            |     5 |    10 |
|                     | Resident Locked Out           |     2 |       |
|                     | Smoke  Alarm not working      |     1 |       |
|                     | Tub - Clogged (1 Bathroom)    |     1 |       |
|                     | Leaking Water                 |     1 |       |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+
```

What I want to do is if the PropertyName is the same as the previous row succeeding row should be omitted. This should be the same for the Total.

I can't try `LAG/LEAD` because we are only using `SQL SERVER 2008` - i know it's a bummer.

Comment: You have two choices in SQL 2008. Use a report writer application (which should be able to do this for you), or use a cursor in your SQL and keep track of it yourself, outputting the information as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate row numbers in a CTE expression, then select top most row numbers per `PropertyName`:

```
  ;with tableWithRowNums as( 
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum, 
            PropertyName,
            Emergency,
            Count,
            Total
    from the_table ),
  first_rows as (
    select min(rownum) as first_row,
            PropertyName 
    from tableWithRowNums
    group by rowNums.PropertyName
  )
  select ISNULL(first_rows.PropertyName, ''),
        tableWithRowNums.Emergency,
        tableWithRowNums.Count,
        tableWithRowNums.Total  
  from tableWithRowNums
    left join first_rows on first_rows.first_row = tableWithRowNums.rownum
  order by tableWithRowNums.rownum;
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is better done at the application level.  But, in your case, yo just seem to want the values on the "No" row.  You can do this with some `case` expressions:

```
select (case when Emergency = 'No' then PropertyName end) as PropertyName,
       Emergency, Count,
       (case when Emergency = 'No' then Total end) as total
from t
order by max(total) over (partition by PropertyName) desc,  -- you seem to want the largest total first
         t.PropertyName, 
         (case when Emergency = 'No' then 1 else 2 end),
         t.Total desc;
```

The `ORDER BY` is very important.  SQL queries are not guaranteed to return results in any particular order *unless the outermost `SELECT` has an `ORDER BY`*.

Comment: It is an interesting approach, but only works if you can guarantee that there will be a line where `Emergency = 'No'` for all properties.

Comment: @LaughingVergil . . . All the sample data is structured like this.  The OP -- in fact -- suggests that this is the entire table.  There is no reason to think that any other rule is being used.